# Команда для терминала не выполняется из Java-кода

Tags: java, bash, debian

Хочу управлять терминалом из Java-кода. Команды "ls", "pwd" выполняются, а при вводе  команды "cd /home" влетают исключения, хотя команда корректная:

[image: Работа команды в терминале]

```
Неверная команда
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": error=2, Нет такого файла или каталога
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, Нет такого файла или каталога
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 4 more
```

Как это исправить? Код программы привожу ниже. Моя ОС - Debian 9.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String cmd = "cd /home";
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = null;
        try {
            pr = run.exec(cmd);
            pr.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Неверная команда");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Процесс прерван");
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while (true) {
            try {
                if ((line = buf.readLine()) == null) break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Ошибка ввода-вывода");
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java

Comment: Терминал  -- это конечное приложение, чтобы им управлять, надо послать соответствующие события через систему window management'а, например, X11 протокол. Так же есть варианты типа RDP & VNC. Но судя по описанию, вы хотите совсем не этого,

Comment: Потому что ls, pwd это настоящие приложения (лежат в /bin), а cd это внутренняя команда оболочки (в вашем случае скорее всего bash). Ну и если вы хотели поменять текущий каталог вашей программы, то это делается не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Комментаторы правы. Я не хотел менять каталоги. Мне нужно было просмотреть файлы из другой директрории. Это делатся командой `ls`